# How can I run a test perl script designed for prove form inside TextMate?

Tags: perl, textmate, modulino

I'm using TextMate 1.5.10 (Mac OSX 10.7.2) to write a [perl modulino application](http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/18.modulinos.html). To verify the functionality, I'm using test scripts designed to be run with the `prove` command line tool.

An example of the directory structure I'm using looks like this:

```
text_mate_test/MyModule.pm
text_mate_test/t/001_load_test.t
```

The 001_load_test.t file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use Modern::Perl;
use Test::More;
use MyModule;

my $testObj = new_ok("MyModule", undef, "Initial load test.");

done_testing();
```

When I run `prove` or `prove -v` in the "text_mate_test" directory, everything passes as expected.

I'd like to be able to setup a hotkey in TextMate that allows me to run the test file without having to jump over to the terminal. Currently, if I run "001_load_test.t" directly from inside TextMate with Cmd+R, it chokes saying "Can't locate MyModule.pm in @INC". That's expected since the test script isn't designed to run directly. (I'm still pretty new to writing test files, but I believe that's the proper way to set them up.)

Running off the assumption that I don't want to change the test file itself, is there a way to setup a hotkey so I can run the file accurately from inside TextMate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out an even better way to do this.

In the TextMate Bundle Editor (Menubar -> Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Show Bundle Editor), I've updated the default "Perl -> Run Script" bundle to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "#{ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"]}/lib/tm/executor"
require "#{ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"]}/lib/tm/save_current_document"

TextMate.save_current_document
TextMate::Executor.make_project_master_current_document

### If it's a ".t" test script in a "t" directory, run prove
if ( ENV["TM_FILEPATH"] =~ /^.*\/(t\/[^\/]+)$/ )

    ### Grab the relative file path for more legible output
    relative_file_path = $1

    ### Jump up one directory so prove will work
    Dir.chdir("../");

    ### Call prove with args to run only the file you are working on.
    TextMate::Executor.run("prove", :script_args => ["-v", relative_file_path]);

### Otherwise, run with perl
else
    TextMate::Executor.run(ENV["TM_PERL"] || "perl", "-I#{ENV["TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT"]}", 
        "-Mexception_handler", ENV["TM_FILEPATH"], 
        :version_args => ["-e", 'printf "Perl v%vd", $^V;'])
end
```

Here's a screenshot of how it looks in the Bundle Editor.

[image: TextMate Bundle Editor Screen Shot for using prove to run perl test scripts]

The benefit of this is that you can use the same hot key (Cmd+r by default) to run your normal scripts with perl and your test scripts with prove.

This is what I was looking for.

---

*UPDATED: When I first developed this, I only had one test script in the "t" directory. I didn't notice until I added other test scripts that the code in the original version of this answer would run prove across all the scripts. Not just the one being worked on. To get back to the expected behavior, I've update the bundle code so that prove will only run on the active script.*

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution. Create a new Perl bundle called "Run Script with prove" and associate it with Shift-Cmd-R. The code for the bundle is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "#{ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"]}/lib/tm/executor"
require "#{ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"]}/lib/tm/save_current_document"

TextMate.save_current_document
TextMate::Executor.make_project_master_current_document


### If it's a ".t" test script in a "t" directory, run prove
if ( ENV["TM_FILEPATH"] =~ /^.*\/(t\/[^\/]+)$/ )

    ### Use the relative file path for more legible output
    relative_file_path = $1

    ### Jump up one directory so prove will work
    Dir.chdir("../");

    ### Call prove with args to run only the file you are working on.
    TextMate::Executor.run("prove", :script_args => ["-v", relative_file_path]);

else

    error_string = "This script's filepath doesn't end with /t/.*\.t\n"
    error_string += "That is required for the 'Perl -> Run Script with prove' bundle to work.\n"

    TextMate::Executor.run("echo", :script_args => [error_string]);

end
```

*Note: This is the results of a bunch of trial and error hacking. I don't know if it's the "right" to do it, but this works for me. Everything but the last two lines is a copy from the original "Run Script" bundle that comes with TextMate. Based on that, it seems like this should be pretty safe.*

*UPDATE: When I first built this I only had one test file in the "t" directory. When I added more, I discovered that the original version of the bundle was running all the test files. This code represents an update to the expected behavior of only running the test script you working on. Because of the way I ended up doing that, it also became necessary to add in a fallback. If you try to run a script that doesn't match the standard test file path format, it gives an error message.*

Comment: I put in another answer that I think is even better. It allows one hotkey to be used for both regular perl scripts and for test scripts. I'm leaving this one here though in case someone is looking for a way to setup separate hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

It will enable the program to find your module if you add

```
use lib '..';
```

to the top of your code (before the `use MyModule`). This will add the `text_mate_test` directory to @INC and enable Perl to find the module, though you may come across other problems with running the program directly.